# How to get SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I need to get the time since the last reboot, for in-game timer.

Standard "DateTime.Now" is not suitable because it can be easily hacked by changing the system time. and I want the game to work completely offline.  I saw games that implemented this, I found the "Elapsed_stamp" variable in the playerPrefs files, which was exactly the time since the system was rebooted.  This means it is possible to read this data offline, but I don’t know how

Answer (score 0):

you can make an api call with unity's UnityEngine.Networking.
Note that you'll have to set up logic to ensure the user has an internet connection, what to do if they don't, etc. If I remember right Unity also makes that pretty easy with their mobile packages.

Here's an example to get you started with worldtimeapi.org:

```cs
private IEnumerator GetCurrentTime()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Toronto"))
    {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        if (webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error: " + webRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string jsonResponse = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Parse(jsonResponse);

            Debug.Log("Current Time: " + currentTime);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're feeling lazy, in my little idle game I just made it so if the users system time is less than the previously logged system time their save file gets wiped and I warn them about it lol.

Comment: The thing is that I chose this option (reading elapsedrealtime) because it does not require the Internet.  There are many games on Google Play that work without the Internet and are not hacked by system time.  Having rummaged through one of these games in the player prefs, I found the elapsed_stamp variable storing "elapsedrealtime"

Comment: Ah, sorry I was on lunch and read your question a bit too quickly then. I didn't know there were offline solutions to this so you got me curious too. I would have thought elapsedrealtime was a measure of the players time spent in game for tracking/engagement etc.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing the question clearly, I will look for an offline solution, but if I don’t find it, I’ll use the solution you suggested, thank you

Comment: I solved this problem by creating a plugin in Android studio that returns elapsedrealtime, it's pretty simple